# Ruby class method inheritance, how to stop the child method from executing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop

This question pertains to a Ruby on Rails problem but this simplified problem will give me the solution I am looking for.

I have two classes, the child class is inheriting a parent method, but I want to half the execution of the child method code if certain conditions are met in the parent method.

```
class A

  def test_method
    puts 'method1'
    return false
  end

end

class B < A

  def test_method
    super
    #return false was called in parent method, I want code to stop executing here
    puts 'method2'
  end

end

b = B.new
b.test_method
```

And the output is:

```
method1
method2
```

My desired output is:

```
method1
```

Does anyone know how to achieve my desired output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use simple `if-end` statement:

```
class B < A
  def test_method
    if super
      puts 'method2'
    end
  end
end
```

Now, `B#test_method` will return `false` if super returns `false`. Otherwise it evaluates code inside `if-end` block.

Comment: Thanks.  The answer is much simpler when you see it!

Answer (score 3):

```
class B < A
  def test_method
    super and puts 'method2'
  end
end
```

This way both will run, if super is anything except `nil` or `false`

Alternatively, you can use the stronger precedenced `&&` but this lower precedence is often used as flow control.

See [Avdi's blog post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) about this.